# Do Value objects have behaviour?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In his book, Eric Evans distinguishes between value classes and entity classes.  Value objects do not have an identity and continuity.

Do Value classes contain behaviour? Is it acceptable for Value Types not to have behaviour? The reason I ask is because a rich domain model differs from an anemic one in the sense that classes contain state and behaviour.  I am trying to create a rich domain model, however I am finding myself creating value objects with no behaviour.

Therefore I wonder if my domain model is anemic (because the value types do not contain behaviour) and rich (because the entity types do contain behaviour).

Comment: An answer is in the second part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235091/are-dto-anemic-model-anemic-value-object/44236273#44236273

Comment: @Constantin GALBENU, I am talking about Value objects in the domain model rather than DTO objects used to transfer data between two application domains e.g. two app domains separated by a WCF web service.

Comment: I understand, I know, that's why I pointed you to the second part of the answer: "A Value object has behavior (behavior for read). For example, it implements the behavoir to test if two value objects are equal or not."

Comment: @COME FROM, is it acceptable for Value types not to contain any behaviour.  Does this make them anemic?

Comment: @Constantin GALBENU, thanks that makes sense.  Just to confirm; a value type that contains only two methods (.equals and .hascode) does not make a domain model anaemic?

Comment: "Domain model" refers to the Entities, not Value Objects (which are immutable), thus "anemy" makes sense only in the context of Entities (in fact Aggregates)

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Value objects need not to be immutable. This is a point of controversy between different sects of DDD (with the immutable-party being way, way more vocal), but there is nothing wrong per se in having mutable value objects. It boils down to preference, in this case.

Comment: @TSar Eric Evans's and Vaughn Vernon's sect says that they should be immutable.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU And so what? They are just two authors in a world of developers. Even Martin Fowler says some bullshit from time to time. It's not why someone put something in a book that this is a holy dictate to be followed. _Cargo Cult Programming_ is a poison - avoid it. You should think by yourself and use the authors' books as suggestions, not rules to be followed by the letter.

Comment: @TSar In the general context you are correct but I also agree with their saying. From my experience immutability in this context is a gold rule.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I'm not saying it's not useful. However, one can find use cases for mutable value objects, and several other types of worker objects that hold a temporary, volatile, state but have no persistent identity. Sometimes the mutability having side effects is desirable. It boils down to what you are trying to implement - having golden rules introducing artificial restraints is a bad thing. I interpret immutable value objects as maybe a _gold suggestion_ as in a generally good idea, but something I can toss away if I can do something in a clearer and more maintainable way otherwise.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Remember: quite a few authors bashed ORM Frameworks as a fad and a silly thing a few years ago, and nowadays ORMs are almost indispensable. They can be _wrong_ sometimes, too.

Comment: @TSar I understand and I agree. But one should think again when he wants to make a `VO` mutable. If he still wants then it is OK.

Comment: "* I am trying to create a rich domain model...*" That's the start of your problem, right there.

Comment: @David Arno, why? I take it you are a fan of anemic domain models?

Comment: @w0051977, I certainly am. The "rotten domain model" forces you down the path of mutating state, which is, in most cases, a "bad thing".

Comment: @DavidArno 'The "rotten domain model" forces you down the path of mutating state' - I find this to be a completely artificial construction.  It does no such thing.  Immutability and rich domains are like peas in a pod.

Comment: @DavidArno Anemic domain models being a "bad thing" is one of the things that heavily bothers me in recent times. I'm glad that you are one of the voices that support it as a viable way of developing software. I'm with you on this train!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction between value types and entities is largely independent of the amount of behavior that a class has.

- For entities, it is very unusual that they don't have behavior and that would be almost certainly an indication of an anemic domain model.
- For value types, you can have them with very rich behavior (like `String`) or with no behavior at all (typically DTO classes).

If you want to keep away from anemic domain models, then you should avoid entities without behavior. That is, classes where multiple copies of an object shouldn't compare equal but that also don't contain behavior.

Comment: Don't force behavior where it doesn't belong, however. It's entirely possible to have one or more entity classes with no behavior at all because they are just that simple - just data containers to be used somewhere else that are persisted in the database. Forcing behavior where shouldn't be none is as bad as putting needed behavior somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. So value types that do not contain behaviour (only .equals and .hashcode) do not make the domain model anemic? It is entities without behaviour that make a domain model anemic.  Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: nitpicking: `String` is a reference type.

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, you understand that correctly, but also take the comment from @TSar into account. A few entity classes without behavior is not a problem, but the majority without behavior is.`

Answer (score 4):

> Do Value classes contain behaviour?

Evans, *Domain Driven Design*

> An object that represents a descriptive aspect of the domain with no conceptual identity is called a VALUE OBJECT....  Treat the VALUE OBJECT as immutable.  Don't give it any identity, and avoid the design complexities necessary to maintain entities.

[Value objects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) are representations of immutable state, using spellings taken from the language of your domain.

Which typically means that they will support queries that return other Value objects, but they won't support any commands, and they won't have any side effects.

Another way of expressing the same idea: they are a remedy against [primitive obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession/).

They are a way of insulating the *domain model* from the details of the underlying *data model*.

In object oriented programming, "behavior" is normally associated with a change of state.  So no, a Value object doesn't do that.  Typically, instead of changing itself, what the value object will do is return a new immutable object describing the same state.

For instance, consider List.add(...)

If List is an *entity*, then the usual implementation of add is to mutate the internal representation of the list (ie, the data structure hidden behind the abstraction).

```
List theList = List.of(1,2,3)
assert theList.size() == 3

theList.add(4);
assert theList.size() == 4
```

If List is a *value object*, then the usual implementation of add returns a new List object without changing the original.

```
List source = List.of(1,2,3)
assert source.size() == 3

List target = source.add(4)
assert target.size() == 4
assert source.size() == 3
```

Comment: if I need to export the content of my Value Object to a csv file. Can I put a method inside my own VO or is it better to have a separated class for csv operations?

Comment: "Create a csv representation of this data" doesn't sound like a _domain_ concern, so Evans would probably suggest that the implementation belongs somewhere else.  Your CSV data is a kind of message, and the schema for that message may belong closer to the boundary.  Your domain model is harder to change when your domain code is mixed with a bunch of non domain concerns.  Changes that affect both the domain model and your messaging are easier when those concerns are close together.  Take a guess, keep track of how it turns out.

Answer (score 3):

Anemia does not make sense in the context of Value objects, but in the context of Entities, especially Aggregates.

However, Value objects can have some kinds of behavior (like formatting, conversions, computations) but the purpose of that behavior is different from the behavior found in Entities.